# Better way to manage a duplicated id name... attributes

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I work in a project that can receive a multiple `HTML` fragments, each fragment could be sent from a different users, in fact some fragments could contain the same id name or `CSS` class name, how to manage the duplicated names, and target them in `JS` or `PHP` `DOM`?

Comment: can you [purify](http://htmlpurifier.org/) them?

Answer (score 1):

If you can store the fragments in JavaScript (AJAX or whatever) then you can try this on the page - it should work on any device and fixes any duplicate ID by renaming it with a random number before adding it to the DOM

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YAjDU/)

```
 $(function() {
  var counter=0,prefix="renFrag",fragments = [
      $('<div id="id1">Fragment1</div>'),
      $('<div id="id2">Fragment2</div>'),
      $('<div id="id3">Fragment3</div>')
  ]  
  $.each(fragments,function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id"); // the ID of the fragment
      if ($("#"+id).length>0) { // find if this ID is already in the DOM
    // rename the fragment. NOTE Date().getTime() was not random enough 
    // $(this).attr("id",id+'_'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)); 
        $(this).attr("id",prefix+(counter++)); 
      }  
      $(this).appendTo("#container"); // add the fragment to the DOM
  });
  $("div").each(function() { // display the ID for debugging (remove when happy)
      $(this).append("-"+this.id); 
  });  
});
```

If you need access to the new fragment, add a fixed string to it, change the random to a counter and use `$("div[id^=renFrag]").whatever` or `$("div[id=renFrag"+cnt+"]").whatever`

If there are embedded scripts and CSS you need to preserve, an option which is not normally recommendable but your case is special, is to load each fragment in its own iFrame. Please be aware that executing foreign scripts in the page or via iFrames is a security risk.

Comment: @Seth Your comment makes no sense. It **fixes** any duplicate `id` elements by changing the `id`.

Comment: @mplungjan You're right, sorry, I mis-read the first time. I changed the downvote to up.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks first, so that's for client side and server side i think i'll do the same, but how to target them for example document.getElementById('which string i'll put here')? i can't predict the new id...

Comment: @mplungjan ok right, but what's if the fragment Contains a externel link to JS file or a CSS style tag, which targeted the id name with the basic(original) name?

Comment: Then you are SOL. You are in fact trying to write a browser in a browser. If you have these problems, load all fragments in iframes

Comment: @mplungjan ooohhh yeehhhss :), ok but iframes and SEO are not a friends!! what about XMLNS? can it be a solution?

Comment: I do not see a SEO issue - especially if you ajax or insert the data later. a spider would follow a URL to a fragment anyway... Where would namespaces help ?

Comment: @mplungjan i'll test it. well i'think warapping fragement with an namespace prefixes and in PHP use DOMElement::setAttributeNodeNS and in JS use getElementsByTagNameNS...

Comment: And how will that help the script that expects a specific ID?

Comment: @mplungjan :) i don't know, i'll put a terms to be respected for any developer. The problem is how to implement the solution? and if the result will be rendred in all browsers especially for old ie, because a content-type xhtml xml is not supported by the old ie... i try to found a eficient solution if not i'll use your's...

Answer (score -1):

If you know what unique ids to search for, you can easily replace exact strings using str_replace in PHP:

```
$html = str_replace(array('id="test1"', 'id="test2"'), array('id="new1"', 'id="new2"'), $html);
```

To search for and replace CSS class names in a string in PHP, you can use preg_replace. There could be multiple class names on an HTML node, so a regular expression can parse this better.

Comment: sorry yes right class could be declared more than one time. The regexp could be a solution but how the JS DOM or PHP DOM can predict the  id name?

Comment: @kapsula If you do not know what the ids will be named exactly then you can also use preg_replace. It would be better to to get rid of any duplicate ids in PHP before trying to bring into the JavaScript DOM, because you are not allowed duplicate ids on the same page.